# why is makeblastdb not working with syntax error

Tags: python, database, biopython, blast

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/minhlam/ncbi-blast-2.10.1+/bin/db')
makeblastdb -in human.fa -db mouse.fa -out mousedb -outfmt 5
```

The error is:

```
  File "parseBlast.py", line 5
    makeblastdb -in human.fa -db mouse.fa -out mousedb -outfmt 5
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've checked multiple pages and other resources and this is just how you write it. Any help would be appreciated.

In general, I want to do a local blast search. I have 2 fasta files, one human.fa and one mouse.fa. I need to format the mouse.fa via makeblastdb and then run the blast. First month with python and need some help.

Answer (score 1):

`makeblastdb -in human.fa -db mouse.fa -out mousedb -outfmt 5` is a CLI command (ie a command you type in the terminal / shell / CMD).

It is **not** a valid Python syntax.

If you do want to execute it from within a Python script, you can use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
import sys
import subprocess

sys.path.append('/home/minhlam/ncbi-blast-2.10.1+/bin/db')

p = subprocess.Popen(['makeblastdb', '-in', 'human.fa', '-db', 'mouse.fa', '-out', 'mousedb', '-outfmt', '5'])
```